# Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzdz

Tags: android, firebase, build.gradle

I'm trying to update dependencies to the latest versions. I install the new version that Android Studio offers at the prompt. But when you start the application, this error occurs:

```
Error: Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzdz
```

My build.gradle (module):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId '***'
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary true
        renderscriptTargetApi 27
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.6'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.35.0'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

My build.gradle (project):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

How can you avoid this error? What dependencies conflict?

**UPDATE:**

If I tried to change the version of firebase-core to

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase: firebase-core: 16.0.4'
```

In this case, the application runs without error, but Android Studio highlights this line:

[image]

Comment: Its OK with highlight, Android Studio notify that dependency is not last version. Wait until Google release 16.0.6 or higher

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed with `play-services-ads:17.1.1` and `firebase-core:16.0.5`.

Comment: Excellent! Version `17.1.1` has appeared. At the time of writing the post, the latest version was `17.1.0`. Now everything works if I replace as you wrote. Thanks you.

Comment: Wow, thanks. This really saved my day. I don't get why Google doesn't update it's docs correctly. Really hard to figure out...